# What kind of matrix barcode is this?

Tags: barcode, qr-code, aztec-barcode

I first assumed the image below was a QR code, but upon closer inspection, it seems to be something else (note, for example, the calibration square in the middle of the matrix).

[image]

Does anybody know what such a dot matrix is called?  Are there any tools available to decode it (Python would be ideal...)?

Many thanks!

Comment: maybe related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code

Comment: @Hacketo, indeed it is!  Feel free to submit this as an answer and I will gladly accept!

Comment: I don't know this tech, feel free to answer your own question :) (if it's really aztec code)

Comment: I was able to answer this question by searching the internet for "online barcode reader" and uploading your image to the first returned website :/

Comment: @nekomatic, congratulations on your google-fu.  I was having a bit more trouble with my keywords.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be snarky. It's always easier to find something when you already know it exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This barcode symbology is Aztec, as @Hacketo pointed out. Characterized by the finder pattern made of concentric square rings. Specifications for this symbology can be found here: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=41548

ZXing is a very popular open source option for barcode recognition. They have beta support for the Aztec symbology. You can access the github project here: github.com/zxing/zxing

I've seen some Python ports of this library however they seem to only support QR. 
github.com/holizz/pyxing granted no commits have been made in a while.